# Plot multiple barplots on one plot, but bars dont overlap R

Tags: r

If I wanted to do this with the bars of the different calls to barplot(add=T) overlapping, that's fine and dandy. But say I want tthem to be plotted on the same plot, but with the first call having a ylim from 0:1 then the second call from 1:2 etc. I tried:

```
for(i in 1:length(files)) { 
file <- as.matrix(read.table(files[i], header=F, sep=" ") )
if(i==1) barplot(file, beside=T, col=1:i, border=NA, ylim = c(0,length(files))) 
if(i>1) barplot(file, beside=T, col=1:i, border=NA, ylim = c(i-1,i) ,xpd=T, add=T)  
}
```

but that overlays them. How can I do it so that theyre on the same image but not overlapping if that makes sense. I envisage something like this http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/5439/romak13.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing something like this, I'd recommend using ggplot2, as it's much easier.

Here's some sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat,y=price,fill=color))+
geom_histogram(stat='identity')+
facet_grid('cut~.',scale='free')+labs("Graph Title")
```

The output looks like this:[image]

The interpretation of this particular graph is a bit strange, considering the nature of the data set, but if you follow the same format, you should be able to get a decent-looking graph.  If anyone has any better data examples, let me know.